# Is there a period after a greeting?

Tags: commas, email, greetings, periods

For example, when writing an email to an associate saying

> Good afternoon, Joel.

Or should there be a comma instead of the period?

Answer (score 2):

No, there should not be a full stop. Usually a greeting would be succeeded by a comma like so:

> Good afternoon Joel,
>
> -insert message here-
>
> Thank you,
>
> Sasha

Comment: By the way, "full stop" is typical BrE, "period" is typical AmE.